# Can't interact with confirmed public question

Tags: bug, editor

Click to ask a question, fill all the available boxes, click outside the boxes, change tab or close Chrome and leave it like that for a few minutes.

If you do that and come back to it, then it won't allow you to add text to the available boxes (title, body, tags), to select "Answer your own question" and to click "Discard draft" and "Review your question". To then be able to do it, then you'd have to unselect "Confirm this is a public question..." and select it again.

See it in the next images

[image: 1st]

[image: 2nd]

[image: 3rd]

This was reproduced using Chrome on Android and was only able to do it in main site.

Comment: *"Public question"*? Shouldn't this be tagged with *Stack Overflow for Teams* or similar?

Comment: Nice observation @PeterMortensen considering people without teams might not see that initial selection box and there's space for them to not have this bug.

Comment: Are you able to see if there is some sort of JS error or if some request failed in the browser console?

Comment: @user4642212 could reproduce it again but do you know how to check the console using Chrome on Android? (Most likely will need to connect the phone to the computer)

Comment: @TiagoMartinsPeres李大仁 No, I’ve never done something like this, I don’t know.

Comment: @user4642212 already know [how](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging) and started the process. But I'm using a Huawei and required HiSuite both in the computer and in the phone (and the phone was very low in memory) but I reckon now is installing (the app showed up, no progress bar for installation but once clicking in it the app closes right away). Will write once know more info.